# When creating a separation method in gas chromatography, calibration with compounds mixture or for each separate component?

Tags: chromatography, separation-techniques

When creating a separation method in gas chromatography, is there any difference between the calibration with the compounds mixture and the calibration for each separate component? I have 5 components.

Comment: Note that there are often mixed standards with 10-20 components.

Comment: In gas chromatography, the response factor depends only on the concentration of the component in the solution to be analyzed. It does not depend on the presence of internal standards.